# How to remove a range from a master range in excel formula

Tags: excel-formula

I've been trying to extract a list using a formula, removing duplicates and sorting it in alphabetical order. The array formula I have used is

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(rt04client, MATCH(MIN(IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1 rt04client)=0,COUNTIF(rt04client, "<"&rt04client)+1,9.9999E+307)), COUNTIF(rt04client, "<"&rt04client)+1, 0)),"")
```

where rt04client is the range name.
The formula works perfectly but the problem I have is that I have a few names from that list that I would like to ignore. I have name ranged that list as Developer.

How would I be able to subtract developer from rt04client?

P.s. All the range is text
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just add another countifs() to the IF statement `COUNTIF(Developer,rt04client)=0`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(rt04client, MATCH(MIN(IF((COUNTIF($A$1:A1,rt04client)=0)*(COUNTIF(Developer,rt04client)=0),COUNTIF(rt04client, "<"&rt04client)+1,9.9999E+307)), COUNTIF(rt04client, "<"&rt04client)+1, 0)),"")
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of 
Enter when exiting edit mode.  If don correctly Excel will put {}` around the formula.

The idea is the if both are true then it resolves to 1 or True if either is false it resolves to 0 or False.

[image]

Comment: Thanks scott. Works like a charm. :) :) :)

Comment: @AlexDanovich please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.

Comment: Just for more info: What if there were multiple criteria?